# PHP: What happens to stored object references when they get stored in $_SESSION

Tags: php

What happens to object references when they are stored in the session container ($_SESSION)?

In this process, when the values are serialized, are the object references converted into copies or do they simply get broken?

```
session_start();
$testArrayA = [];
$testArrayB = [];    
$testArrayA["abc"] = &$testArrayB;
$testArrayB["def"] = "test2";
$_SESSION["myvalue"] = $testArrayA;
```

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: You could test this yourself by implementing storing sessions in your database.

Comment: I'd rather test it by serializing an array that contains twice the same reference. My bet is that both references end up as different copies, but that might not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the session is written, it gets serialized.  Serialization does not care about references at all since it just reads the data (if it's reading from a reference it will resolve the reference's target).

You can see this behavior by changing the last line to:

```
var_dump(serialize($testArrayA));

string(44) "a:1:{s:3:"abc";a:1:{s:3:"def";s:5:"test2";}}"
```

That's what gets stored in the session.

Note that if an object implements `__sleep` or the `Serializable` interface its serialization behavior is unique.  I believe that `PDO` overrides serialization behavior to destroy its database connection reference.